# 2-ball billiards in a circle

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, computational-complexity, billiards, chaos

Consider a 2D circular billiards table with diameter 1m containing two
balls with diameter 0.25m.  Let each ball start with a speed of 1m/s.
In general, this speed could change after the balls hit each other, but in
the symmetric cases considered below, it will not (just the direction
changes).

To make this even simpler, assume "inversion-symmetric" initial conditions as in the first figure below, or "mirror-symmetric" initial conditions which are equivalent to the second figure.  Only the second case appears chaotic (see my paragraph below all figures), so it seems that its computation
time, to determine the ball's position at a large time T, will scale linearly
with T (actually a little slower than linearly, due to needing more bits for
numerical precision).

If I can't afford linear computation time, is the best predictor for the position
of the ball just the uniform distribution over the semicircle?

I wonder if this might not even be uniform in the limit of infinite T.

I also wonder if there is anything at all (e.g., the probability of one ball
being within 0.1m of its initial position for "conveniently-chosen large T") that
I can compute/predict faster-than-linearly.

[image]

[image]

If the "inversion-symmetric" case has a gap, large T can be analyzed quickly because the balls never hit each other:

[image]

Even when the gap is negative so that the balls hit each other, I believe
the same "scatter deflection angle" just repeats in time, so all
"inversion-symmetric" cases can be analyzed quickly, leaving just the
"mirror-symmetric" chaos to think about.